# Deploy two services on one machine

Tags: service, jvm

I have a 4c8g machine. I deployed the same service to two ports. The maximum memory of each service jvm is 3g.

Someone suggested that I would only deploy one instance on a machine.

Can someone tell me what are the advantages and disadvantages of these two methods?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you ask that "someone"? I do not see this question getting a clear answer here.

Comment: You can run as many JVMs as you want within reason.  If they use a total of 6 GB on an 8 GB machine I don't see a problem.

Comment: @PeterLawrey When jvm runs for a while, the free memory space will become smaller and smaller. Is it too much for jvm to be allocated?

Comment: @FrankDsc The JVM cleans up memory as required, so the only time you know how much is really retained is after a full GC. If this is growing tofill up main memory or the max heap size then that is a problem.

Answer (score 0):

There are two advantages I see to running multiple instances in the way you describe:

1. You are paying for an 8Gb machine, of which you're only using 3Gb.  Running a second instance brings that up to 6Gb which is a much more effective use of the resources you have.
2. By running two instances of the same service on a single machine you can take advantage of class sharing (and application class data sharing if you use the latest JVM) to improve the resource utilisation of your services further.